# Play constraint messages with arguments

Tags: validation, playframework, internationalization, constraints, externalizing

I'm trying to make a list of generic externalized messages in the play framework but can't find or figure out the syntax to pass parameters to these messages within objects that I'm creating. I can successfully used the error messages I've created without the arguments.

I've tried several different ways of declaring the arguments but nothing works
Example:

conf/messages:
error.number.fixed={0} must be {1} digits

```
public class Customer {
@Required(message = "error.number.fixed('Phone', '10')" )
public String phone;
}
```

Output:
{"id":["error.number.fixed('Phone', '10'"]}

Without the arguments, the following works:

```
public class Customer {
@Required(message = "error.number.fixed" )
public String phone;
}
```

Output:
{"id":["[] must be {1} digits"]}

Answer (score 0):

Figured this one out.

Had to create a phone number annotation with phoneType as property.

`public @interface PhoneNumber { 
    String message() default "error.phoneNumber";`

...

```
String phoneType();
```

...

`}`

Then set the first argument ({0}) in the messages:

`error.phoneNumber={0} must be 10 digits.`

Then when using the annotation set phonetype as the first (in this case) the only argument for the annotation.

`@PhoneNumber(phoneType="MDN")`

Please correct me if anyone sees a better way of handling this.